# How to read, then write chunk by chunk a large file in java

Tags: java, performance, java-stream, java-io

I have a **large 100mb file** to be read and write.

```
String fromFile1 = "file1.zip"; // 100mb file
String toFile2 = "file2.crypt"; // empty

In a loop
 1. String chunk1 = fromFile1.read("50kb"); // I read in every loop 50kb
 2. toFile2.write(chunk1); //  I write in every loop 50kb
```

After loop end, all content transfered from `file1.zip` to `file2.crypt`.

```
Here by this concept I can avoid reading the entire file into memory
```

How can I do it most efficiently in java?

Comment: Use a CipherOutputStream in combination with buffered streams - this way you hold the memory usage small.

Comment: Why is `chunk1` a `String`?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a large file

Use `Files.newInputStream` to get a stream, which does not read the entire thing into memory and therefore works fine for arbitrary-sized files. The same goes for the output: Get an `OutputStream`. For example with `java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream`.

> to be encrypted

Wrap either the inputstream or the outputstream in a crypto filterstream that is configured accordingly (with the appropriate keys), and then use `in.transferTo(out)` which will cause the entire stream to copy itself, encrypted, without 'memory leaks', into the output stream.

> so I need to read it in chunks of base64 string

Only handrolled horrible crypto works that way, so, no you don't need this.

[Here is an example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cipher-input-output-stream).

Comment: Thank you very much, I cant import newInputStream and newOutputStream

Comment: I tried the example, but here I need to pass all content to `encrypt` function, as here I dont have have any String content, I just have a 100mb file

Comment: They are in `java.nio.files.Files`. If your encrypt method can only encrypt 'entire strings', then you obviously cannot use this method. Follow the link at the end, that's how your encrypt. Whatever you have  right now is probably useless.

Comment: Please have a look again to question as of now simplified

Comment: And my answer is just as good now as it was before. I don't know what your hangup is - that 'here is an example' link does _exactly_ what you want.